# rViz in nvidia-docker container

Tags: docker, nvidia, ros, nvidia-docker

I have set up a bunch of ros nodes that each run inside a docker container and are started via docker-compose. I had no problems running it on my laptop, besides rviz being slow since it was running on the cpu only. Now I am moving the project onto a machine that has an nVidia RTX2080 on ubuntu18.04LTS and the same setup produces these errors. I have already installed nvidia-docker2 and the `daemon.json` is setting the default runtime as nvidia. I don't really know where to start looking at errors. Posts I found were closed without a solution to my problem.

How to get rViz running in nVidia-docker2?

```
rviz_1           | libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
rviz_1           | libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
rviz_1           | libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
rviz_1           | libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
rviz_1           | libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
rviz_1           | libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
rviz_1           | [ INFO] [1576658065.533954900]: rviz version 1.13.6
rviz_1           | [ INFO] [1576658065.534009692]: compiled against Qt version 5.9.5
rviz_1           | [ INFO] [1576658065.534021481]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
rviz_1           | [ INFO] [1576658065.548489531]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
rviz_1           | [ WARN] [1576658065.859692866]: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
rviz_1           | rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
rviz_1           | rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
```

Comment: Is nvidia-docker "outdated"? Latest release is in [September 2020](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker). I guess that only docker is used nowadays, and not nvidia-docker?

Comment: [nvidia-docker is deprecated](https://superuser.com/questions/1636390/is-nvidia-docker-outdated-are-there-cases-where-a-new-project-would-still-r).

Comment: nvidia-docker2 package still installs the tools to enable docker to use nvidia so it's not 'depricated' from that perspective. rather the syntax of nvidia-docker run is depricated in favor of docker run --gpus ....etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration.
Nvidia docker images need to be built by your own.

```
$ cd path/to/dir
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM your-repo/your-image:your-tag
# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
    ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics
$ docker build -t your-nvidia-image .
$ xhost +local:
$ docker run --gpus all -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY your-nvidia-image /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue in docker compose that I recently solved. Added the following into my dockerfile and rebuild:

```
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics
```

And also make sure in compose.yaml, you have set the following:

volume:

```
-"/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"
-"/var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus"
```

enivironment:

```
-"/usr/local/nvidia/bin:${PATH}"
-"NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: all"
-"NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:compute,compat32,utility,graphics,video,display"
- "DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY"
- "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"
- "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR= /run/user/1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I really faced the same problem today. I tested rviz in docker on my CPU laptop and everything worked fine until I tested the setup on a GPU accelerated hardware. I have been able to solve it by using the solution proposed in http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration under "nvidia-docker2".

Obviously, you need to build your image with the environment variables "NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" and "NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES" and run your container with runtime=nvidia. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am forced to use docker-compose, but with setting the nvidia runtime as default in dockers deamon.json it should work anyway. However it doesn't. I couldn't even get the example provided in the ROS Wiki to work(without compose). Any suggestions?